# Magento 2.3.x setup:upgrade fails after sample-data installed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, setup-upgrade, sample-data

I have a clean Magento 2.3.2 in docker container.
After I installed sample data with `bin/magento sampledata:deploy` I cannot run `setup:upgrade` anymore even with `--keep-generated` parameter:

```
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Running data recurring...Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed
```

After I remove sample data `setup:upgrade` works good.

I'm on Ubuntu16, the issue is not reproduced in Windows docker.

We have here a lot of answers about 'theme_dir' but I don't have any custom theme and I did not change anything in configuration nor installed any custom modules so that I decided to post a new question.

---

UPD:
**The issue had gone away when I stopped magento cronjobs.** Probably it was about file permissions or some kind of locks or indexer issues.

Comment: This issue is usually down to the theme in magneto being invalid either with a custom there or incorrect permissions on the vendor folder id recommend checking the permissions on vendor if it is a new install then is going most likely be the answer

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a permission issue. Try to run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

in your Ubuntu Maschine.

Comment: I applied 0777 permissions as you suggested and *stopped my cronjobs* (they could affect permissions or locks).